# session.setAttribute is not giving the selected value

Tags: java, jsp

In this JSP code I am trying to fetch the selected radio button value of value3 and value4 which I have to send to another jsp page.

`session.setAttribute("value3",value3);` is giving me the
last stored value of the loop. I need the selected value of the loop. Can somebody help me on that?

Note: I should not use jquery or other technology.

```
if (DATA != null) {
    ArrayList<HashMap> data1 = DATA;
    for(HashMap<String,String> Hm: data1){
        out.println("<tr class=\"lightrow\">");
        String value1 = Hm.get("dbvalue1");
        String value2= Hm.get("dbvalue2");
        String value3= Hm.get("dbvalue3");
        String value4 = Hm.get("dbvalue4");
        out.println("<td><input type=radio id=db" + " name=db_info size=30 value='" + value1 + "','" + value2
                    + "','" + value3 + "','" + value4 + "'" + "> " + "</td>" ); session.setAttribute("value3",value3);
                    session.setAttribute("value4",value4); out.println("</tr>");
    }
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with JS. It's highly appreciated, that askers would at least know, which language they're working with ...

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. `setAttribute` doesn't "give" any values. On the contrary: it stores them for later use. So your problem is that the HashMap doesn't contain the current data? Then you really need to look into how that HashMap is constructed.

Comment: Hi, you are setting value of session inside loop ofcourse it will give you last value ..Also , what do you mean by selected value ?